# How to handle get and post for web api2 image?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to implement get/post/put/ in web api2 and I want to know what is the best way to implement those methods in the ImageController?

I have seen various implementations to get this done but I want to know what is the best practice?

Comment: You should try explaining what it is you want to do and maybe show some code too.

Comment: I want to build a file server. I want to be able to upload and download images to and from the server. (In web api2)